# Properties of contained class not showing in property designer

Tags: vb.net, properties, propertygrid

I have a class with 2 properties which are instances of other classes. The properties themselves show up in the designer but they are empty, they do not show the properties in the classes they represent even though they are marked as Browsable. What am I missing?

Here is the relevant code section of the classes in question and a snapshot of the designer.
[image]

`Public Class TextBox

```
Inherits Windows.Forms.TextBox

Implements IBoundControl(Of String)
Implements ICustomControl

<Browsable(True), Category(CAT)> Public Property Bound As IBinding(Of String) Implements IBoundControl(Of String).Bound
<Browsable(True), Category(CAT)> Public Property Custom As ICustom Implements ICustomControl.Custom

Public Sub New()
    Me.Bound = New Binding(Of String)("Text", Me)
    Me.Custom = New Custom(Me)
End Sub
```

End Class

Public Class Custom

```
Implements ICustom

<Browsable(True), Category(CAT), DefaultValue(XAlign.None)> Public Property HorzAlign As XAlign Implements ICustom.HorzAlign
    Get
        Return _HorizAlign
    End Get
    Set(value As XAlign)
        _HorizAlign = value
        Me.CustomControl.Location = Me.CreatePoint
    End Set
End Property

<Browsable(True), Category(CAT), DefaultValue(YAlign.None)> Public Property VertAlign As YAlign Implements ICustom.VertAlign
    Get
        Return _VertAlign
    End Get
    Set(value As YAlign)
        _VertAlign = value
        Me.CustomControl.Location = Me.CreatePoint
    End Set
End Property

'.... other methods and properties
```

End Class

`

Tried adding and removing the designer properties in both classes to no avail. I am definitely missing something. Any help greatly appreciated

This is a VB.NET Desktop application

Comment: It depends how you'd expect it to be displayed. Try to add [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))] (not sure about vb.net syntax) to the class to display inner properties https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.expandableobjectconverter for a first run

Comment: Working on it, but so far no luck

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the help, it got me going in the right direction. Here is the correct implementation so that it works properly:

```
Public Class TextBox

Inherits Windows.Forms.TextBox

Implements IBoundControl(Of String)
Implements ICustomControl

<TypeConverter(GetType(ExpandableObjectConverter))>
<Browsable(True), DisplayName("Custom Binding"), Category(CAT),
DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
Public Property Bound As IBinding(Of String) Implements IBoundControl(Of String).Bound


<TypeConverter(GetType(ExpandableObjectConverter))>
<Browsable(True), DisplayName("Special Control"), Category(CAT),
DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
Public Property Custom As ICustom Implements ICustomControl.Custom


Public Sub New()
    Me.Bound = New Binding(Of String)("Text", Me)
    Me.Custom = New Custom(Me)
End Sub
```

End Class

```
Public Class Binding(Of T)

Implements IBinding(Of T)

Private _BoundPropertyName As String
Private _ErrorLog As ILogBook

Private MyControl As Control
Private MyPropInfo As PropertyInfo

Public Sub New(ByVal pPropertyName As String, ByVal pControl As Control)

    Me.MyPropInfo = pControl.GetType.GetProperty(pPropertyName)
    Me.MyControl = pControl

End Sub

<NotifyParentProperty(True)>
<Browsable(False)> <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>
Public Property ErrorLog As ILogBook Implements IBinding(Of T).ErrorLog
    Get
        Return _ErrorLog
    End Get
    Private Set(value As ILogBook)
        _ErrorLog = value
    End Set
End Property

<NotifyParentProperty(True)>
<Browsable(True), Category(CAT), DefaultValue("")>
Public Property BoundPropertyName As String Implements IBinding(Of T).BoundPropertyName
    Get
        Return _BoundPropertyName
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _BoundPropertyName = value
    End Set
End Property

<NotifyParentProperty(True)>
<Browsable(False), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)> Public Property Value As T Implements IBinding(Of T).Value
    Get
        Return CType(MyPropInfo.GetValue(MyControl), T)
    End Get
    Set(value As T)
        MyPropInfo.SetValue(MyControl, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Overrides Function ToString() As String

    Dim TmpName As String = String.Empty

    If BoundPropertyName.ToString = String.Empty Then
        TmpName = "- Unbound -"
    Else
        TmpName = BoundPropertyName.ToString
    End If

    Return String.Format("{0}", TmpName)

End Function
```

End Class